# Differences between mongodb native updateMany and mongoose updateMany

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to update all records on my db collection 'verifications', inside it i have an sub-document called 'documents' (array). I want to remove all documents with steps.length === 0.

Using Mongodb updateMany native method, works:

```
async (next) => {
  try {
    await Verification.collection.updateMany({}, {
      $pull: { documents: { steps: { $size: 0 } } },
    });
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    log.warn('Cannot migrate verifications');
    log.warn(err);
    return next(err);
  }
};
```

But when trying Mongoose updateMany it doesn't work:

```
async (next) => {
  try {
    await Verification.updateMany({}, {
      $pull: { documents: { steps: { $size: 0 } } },
    });
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    log.warn('Cannot migrate verifications');
    log.warn(err);
    return next(err);
  }
};
```

I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: you need to add option ` {multi: true}` so that it checks not only for the first document and update all.

Comment: Thanks, but {multi: true} is useful only when update(), if you use updateMany it is not needed